# Script to monitor directory for creation of a file and modify the file

Tags: bash

When files specifically named xxx.java and yyy.java get downloaded into my Downloads folder I want to automatically patch them in the background transparently using my diff files.

I have tried monitoring the directory using ls but the next step is difficult:-

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

MONITOR_DIR=/home/hduser/Downloads
set x = 1
while : ; do
   cur_files=$(ls ${MONITOR_DIR})
   for i in cur_files
      { 
         if[ "$i" = "xxx.java" ]; then      
          patch $i < foo.patch
          set x = 0
         fi
         if[ "$i" = "yyy.java" ];then
          patch $i < bar.patch
          if [ "$x" eq 0];then break; fi    #doesn't work

         fi
     }

     sleep 4
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make it easy on you, this one is a no brainer:

```
#!/bin/bash

MONITOR_DIR="/home/hduser/Downloads"
PATCHES="/path/where/the/patches/are"  

GoPatch()    { patch "$MONITOR_DIR/$1" < "$PATCHES/$2" ;}    

inotifywait -q -m -e close_write "$MONITOR_DIR" |\
while read _DUMMY DUMMY FILENAME
do
    case "$FILENAME" in
    "xxx.java" ) [ $xflag ] || { xflag=x ; GoPatch xxx.java foo.patch ;} ;; 
    "yyy.java" ) [ $yflag ] || { yflag=x ; GoPatch yyy.java bar.patch ;} ;; 
    "zzz.java" ) [ $zflag ] || { zflag=x ; GoPatch zzz.java bof.patch ;} ;; 
    esac
done
```

Before the patch, we disable the followed path by setting a flag so patching only occurs once per file.

Answer (score 2):

Don't poll !   Use inotifywait.

```
#!/bin/bash

MONITOR_DIR="/home/hduser/Downloads"
PATCHED_DIR="/path/where/the/patched/files/are/moved/to"
PATCHES="/path/where/the/patches/are"  

inotifywait -q -m -e close_write "$MONITOR_DIR" |\
while read _DUMMY DUMMY FILENAME
do
    case "$FILENAME" in
    "xxx.java" ) patch="foo.patch" ;; 
    "yyy.java" ) patch="bar.patch" ;; 
    "zzz.java" ) patch="qqq.patch" ;;
    esac

    mv "$MONITOR_DIR/$FILENAME $PATCHED_DIR/$FILENAME"
    patch "$PATCHED_DIR/$FILENAME" < "$PATCHES/$patch" &
done
```

Inotifywait will sleep until woken up by the OS if a file is written in the directory,
it will output `watched_filename EVENT_NAMES event_filename`
(we will only use event_filename which we read via pipe into FILENAME).

By using the `case` statement, we select a patch.

Then we move the file to another dir and start patching it there (in the background).
While the patching starts we are immediatley ready to wait (sleeping) for the next file.

(oh, and don't forget that the `|\` must **NOT** be followed by space or something else)

Comment: I don't want to patch it in a different directory. It needs to be so that the person watching me never realizes that the fie has been patched

Comment: No problem, just move it back (not copy) after you patched it.

Comment: But that will trigger the loop to patch it again! This is the problem I faced in my script also

Comment: Since inotifywait is set to trigger on close_write it won't trigger on a move because a move is not a write. During a move no file is written, only the directory is changed.